# Livedata observer call multiple times

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-mvvm

i am using mvvm and repository pattern. I have one api call with coroutines and return to livedata and observe live data fragment when click button. One time work normally but second button click viewmodel observe method called multiple times

My ViewModel class

```
@HiltViewModel
class OrderViewModel @Inject constructor (

    private val repository: OrderRepository

):  ViewModel() {

    fun addCourier(body: JsonObject)  = repository.addCourierActivity(body)

}
```

My repository class

```
class OrderRepository @Inject constructor(
private val gpsApi: GpsApi)
{

    private var job: Job? = null

    val mutabLiveData = MutableLiveData<DefaultResponse>()

    /*private val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler {coroutineContext, throwable ->
        mutabLiveData.postValue(DefaultResponse(-1, throwable.message!!))
    }*/



    fun addCourierActivity(body: JsonObject) : LiveData<DefaultResponse> {


        job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val response = gpsApi.addCourierActivity(body)

            Log.e("erer" ,"Coroutine scop called")

            if(response.isSuccessful) {
                mutabLiveData.postValue(response.body())
            } else {
                mutabLiveData.postValue(DefaultResponse(1, "Error"))
            }


        }

        return mutabLiveData
    }
}
```

My fragment class

```
viewmodel.addCourier(body).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {

        Log.e("dfdfdf","Observing livedata")

        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), it.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

Comment: Where's the code for the click?

Comment: Try using SingleLiveEvent : https://proandroiddev.com/singleliveevent-to-help-you-work-with-livedata-and-events-5ac519989c70

Answer (score 0):

checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67660473/singleliveevent-post-if-called-multiple-times-then-only-the-last-event-is-disp/67662388#67662388) it is almost the same as your problem. Try using Event with event observer. Basically, it sends a one-time event to the observer which can be used in your scenario